# Dense Rank Deficient Linear System

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

What are some of the best methods for solving a *Dense Rank Deficient Linear System* $Ax = b$, where $A$ is Dense, Symmetric but possibly Rank Deficient. I know *SVD* can solve it pretty nicely while constraining the solution to be unit which is actually fine for me. But I am wondering if there is a faster method than this. I heard *GMRES* can do good job for Sparse system, how about Dense systems?

Comment: In what sense "rank deficient"? Does it come from an ill-posed problem? Have you tried pivoted QR decomposition? Is it consistent?

Comment: [Here](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719697) you can find a good selection of methods for ill-posed problems.